# How to enable GitLab Container Registry and push docker image in it

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, gitlab-ce

What are the exact steps to enable Container Registry in GitLab Community Edition 14.2.4 using the domain method, and how can I push a docker image to the registry? Also, how can I integrate GitLab CI with the registry?

Specifying only the following string as described in "Configure Container Registry under its domain" not working for GitLab Community Edition 14.2.4

```
registry_external_url 'registry.gitlab.example.com'
```

Comment: Have you read [the container registry admin docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.10/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#enable-the-container-registry) or the [container registry user docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.10/ee/user/packages/container_registry/)? Both these documents should answer your question. If there's something there that's not clear, please provide specifics, what you have tried, what is not working, etc.

Comment: Of course, I have read both, but for me specifying only: registry_external_url 'https://registry.gitlab.example.com' not working. Nothing happens even nginx configuration does not appear after reconfiguration. Probably mentioned approach will work only for Omnibus Gitlab, but I'm using the Community version. After spending a few hours reading outdated (and merged) issues for Gitlab I have found the mentioned solution.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just now realized now you were answering your own question Q&A style.

Answer (score 7):

This is a self-answering topic, I will guide you through the steps to enable Container Registry in GitLab Community Edition 14.2.4 and how to push a Docker image.

**Step 1:** To enable Container Registry, I used the domain method(configuration under existing domain described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#configure-container-registry-under-an-existing-gitlab-domain)). Edit your /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file and add the following lines of code:

```
registry_external_url 'https://registry.example.com'

gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "registry.example.com"

registry['enable'] = true
registry['registry_http_addr'] = "localhost:5000"
registry['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/registry"
registry['env_directory'] = "/opt/gitlab/etc/registry/env"
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 443
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/registry.example.com/fullchain.pem"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/registry.example.com/privkey.pem"
```

After adding these lines, run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. Note that I tried different approaches, including specifying only the `registry_external_url` URL, but nothing worked until I used the above setup. In this article I skipped the security certification steps, this step could be done differently. I have used Let's Encrypt certificates pre-generated and specified for the registry. More information [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/index.html#enable-the-lets-encrypt-integration)

**Step 2:** Once Container Registry is enabled, you can find it in GitLab by navigating to *Project -> Packages & Registries -> Container Registry*. On the empty page, you will find help commands to start working with the registry.

**Step 3:** To integrate GitLab CI with Container Registry, add the following code to your .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
create-image:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  variables:
    VER: 1.0-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    ID: ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  before_script:
    - echo "Docker registry url is $CI_REGISTRY"
    - echo "Docker registry username is $CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    - echo "Docker registry repo is $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  timeout: 12h
  script:
    - docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:$VER ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}

upload-to-registry:
    stage: deploy
    when: manual
    tags:
       - shell
    script:
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:$VER
```